# .NET JWT Refresh Tokens: How to handle requests made while retrieving the new token

Tags: c#, jwt

We wanted to use JSON Web Token (JWT) as API Keys for our new API.  They will be used at the server application level, not given to end users to persists in cache.  It will allow us to be more granular in authorization than basic auth, without sacrificing the simplicity.  Upon researching the idea we found out a service called "Auth0" (https://auth0.com/) is doing exactly this, which seemed to validate our idea.

The thing is that we can't seem to issue JWT indefinitely as .NET "OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions" seems to force us to set an expiration.  We've read about "refresh tokens", but after researching for hours and hours its not really clear what would happen to requests made during the refresh.

e.g. If the client asks for a new token and other requests are being made during the time it takes to retrieve the new JWT, then wouldn't those requests fail?

I found some other platforms allow the old token to remain active for an extra minute to accommodate this scenario (e.g. this post: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-refreshing-jwt-token), but again, it seems not available in .NET.

Can anyone explain the proper methods to refresh a token in .NET, but specifically speak to the matter of honoring requests made while retrieving the new token and saving it in the client?

Updating our question with the code...

Token Generation:

```
private void OAuthTokenGeneration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);

        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            //For Dev enviroment only (on production should be AllowInsecureHttp = false)
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365),
            Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
            AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:live"])
        };

        // OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
    }
```

Authorize...

```
        private void OAuthTokenConsumption(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:live"];
        string audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];
        byte[] audienceSecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"]);

        // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
                IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                {
                    new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, audienceSecret)
                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token should be refreshed before it expires, not after. Both the old and new token will be valid until they eventually expire. In this case, requests made using the old token while it's refreshing will work normally.

---

Here's my recommendation instead of using expiring JWTs + refresh tokens:

`OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` is not related to JWT authentication. I believe you're looking for [`JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.jwt.jwtbearerauthenticationoptions(v=vs.113).aspx) instead. This JWT middleware only validates configured parameters such as audiences, signature, etc. but does not issue tokens, so there's no need to configure an expiration time.

Auth0's API uses JWTs for authentication but there is no service that issues these tokens. Instead, tokens are created by any authorized consumer of the API by using a shared API secret, which is used to sign the token. For example, tokens can be generated locally on the browser and with no expiration date using the [API Explorer](https://auth0.com/docs/api/v2). There is also an endpoint to blacklist tokens by ID (`jti` claim) in case they are compromised or are not needed anymore.

Security-wise one could argue that this is practically equivalent to having an expiring JWT + refresh token, since you need a way to blacklist compromised refresh tokens anyway. It's also easier to understand, doesn't use opaque tokens and makes for a less chatty API.

Comment: We are using `JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions` to authorize, but we issue tokens with `UseOAuthAuthorizationServer` and `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions`.  I think you are suggesting that we forgo this method of issuing the tokens and just keep the authorize part. I suppose that could be an option, but we'd prefer to have a method to generate the tokens for the client (without writing our own).  Do you know of something outside of `UseOAuthAuthorizationServer` that will generate the tokens without an expiration date?  I updated the question with some code.

Comment: Not too familiar with the C# world, but you can use any of the libraries listed at http://jwt.io to manually create JWTs with a configurable expiration date.

Comment: I wanted to thank you for taking the time to reply because I do feel like implementing a custom token provider with tokens that don't expire is a good work around to the problem.  It is perhaps a better solution to my problem than refresh tokens.  However, the original question was how to handle requests made during the time it takes to refresh the token.  I still can't figure out how to handle it.  So I am torn about marking this the answer because it is more of an alternative than the exact answer.

Comment: You're welcome! Updated with an answer to your original question, if I understood it correctly.

Comment: JWT token expiration should be made small if i am right and refreshing of tokens is the best way to implement to my knowledge. I am in the process of refresh token implementation using JWT only,if @user2341148 i will post the answer when i am done :)